# Creating SpatialPolygons in R

Tags: shapefile, r, spatial-analyst, interpolation, kriging

I am trying to do kriging with my data. But there is a problem here. I want to use krige command in gstat package. But I do not have "Spatial object with prediction/simulation locations".

How I can make SpatialPolygons?

I have a shapefile but the problem is that I want to do kriging outside of my shapefile.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to load a shapefile into R as a SpatialPolygons or SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. In which case the answer is to use the `maptools` or `rgdal` package. But this doesn't really have anything to do with kriging (or any particular use you will make of the SpatialPolygons), so I want to make sure I understand the question

Comment: No. I want to create a grid to visualise the output of kriging results.

Comment: The question in this comment ("create a grid to visualise the output of kriging results") is not the same as the question you have posted ("Creating SpatialPolygons in R"). In addition, the gstat package has a lot of options in it. I suggest you edit your question and include a code sample so we can see how far you have got and what you want to accomplish next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing terms and thus, confusing us. The expected input for kriging prediction in the gstat `krige` function is a systematic array of points and not polygons. It would also be nice if you provided a reproducible code example of what you have tried.

You can use the extent of an sp object to create an array of points for the kriging prediction using the `extent`, `raster` and `rasterToPoints` functions in the raster package.

First, we add our libraries and example data (meuse SpatialPointsDataFrame data from sp library).

```
library(gstat)                                         
library(sp)
library(raster)                                            

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x + y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
```

Here we create an extent polygon using a bounding extent of any relevant sp or raster class object. You can then use this extent polygon to create a dummy raster object that is coerced into a SpatialPoints object using `rasterToPoints`. The resulting sp SpatialPoints object can act as the kriging prediction grid.

```
ext <- as(extent(meuse), "SpatialPolygons")
r <- rasterToPoints(raster(ext, resolution = 30), spatial = TRUE)
proj4string(r) <- proj4string(meuse)
```

Now we can specify a kriging model using our point (meuse) and prediction grid (r) objects.

```
# krige model log(copper):                                              
v1 <- variogram(log(copper) ~ 1, meuse)                  
x1 <- fit.variogram(v1, vgm(1, "Sph", 800, 1))           
G1 <- krige(copper ~ 1, meuse, r, x1, nmax = 30)
gridded(G1) <- TRUE                                      
G1@data = as.data.frame(G1@data[,-2])
plot(G1)
```

For some reason the `raster` function was not always honoring the crs argument. I fixed it by assigning the projection, using `proj4string`, after the points were created.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the issue that I wanted to solve it.

Comment: Could you please describe the "proj4string" command? what does it for?

Comment: Another problem:
When I wanted to run <G1 <- krige(zinc ~ 1, meuse, r, x1, nmax = 30)> this error appeared:
Error in predict.gstat(g, newdata = newdata, block = block, nsim = nsim,  : 
  var1 : data item in gstat object and newdata have different coordinate reference systems
>

Comment: The proj4string defines the projection. If this response answered your question pleas mark it as answered so everybody knows that it has been resolved.

Comment: I resolved the error you were receiving. For some reason the projection was not consistently assigning within the raster function. Assigning the projection so they will match, is a critical step. This is done using the proj4string as illustrated in the code example. The "meuse" SpatialPointsDataFrame object is acting in place of whatever data you are using.

Comment: for some reason plot(G1) doesn't work for me, but I can display it with image(G1). Please, how/why have you decided that your resolution will be 30 m? It works well with other values (10, 100..) but my question is if you have somehow reflected the distance between points for meuse data to decide the 30 as the right value? thank you @JeffreyEvans