# R: how to export my Kriging result to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r, kriging

I want to export results of my Kriging calculation to raster or some other format. My aim is to take this converted file and intersect it with another SpatialPointDataFrame (location of the point doesn't have to be the same, so that is the reason of conversion). The goal is equivalent of "Extract values To Points" in ArcGIS - thus, merge information from kriging and another SPDF for one locations.

For second part, I imagine just to use raster::intersect(krig, SPDF).
But how to get raster data for my Kriging? I tried to raster::rasterize

```
r <- raster(ncols = length(ux), nrows = length(uy))  # length(ux), length(uy)
krig.rst<-rasterize(krig.est, r, "var1.pred")
```

and

```
krig.rst<-rasterize(krig.est, r, "var1.pred", fun = function(x, ...) c(min(x))
```

The raster seems to be calculated, but I can't display it.

Please, is the problem in my raster dimension (nrow, ncol, ncell)? How can I assigned it? My first thought was that 1 cell of matrix (from Kriging) will correspond to 1 pixel of raster with assigned value, but I am obviously wrong.

[image]

Long reproductible exemple adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177017/set-automatic-colors-levels-in-filled-contour-kriging

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(RColorBrewer)

# https://rpubs.com/nabilabd/118172
# packages for manipulation & visualization
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr) # for "glimpse"
  library(ggplot2)
  library(scales) # for "comma"
  library(magrittr)
})

data(meuse)

# create spdf
meuse.spdf<-meuse

# convert to spdf
coordinates(meuse.spdf) <- ~ x + y



# calculate voronoi tesselation - will be needed to create underlying point data
voronoipolygons = function(layer) {
  require(deldir)
  crds = layer@coords
  z = deldir(crds[,1], crds[,2])
  w = tile.list(z)
  polys = vector(mode='list', length=length(w))
  require(sp)
  for (i in seq(along=polys)) {
    pcrds = cbind(w[[i]]$x, w[[i]]$y)
    pcrds = rbind(pcrds, pcrds[1,])
    polys[[i]] = Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)), ID=as.character(i))
  }
  SP = SpatialPolygons(polys)
  voronoi = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data=data.frame(dummy = seq(length(SP)), row.names=sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), 
                                                                                                   function(x) slot(x, 'ID'))))
}
meuse.voro <- voronoipolygons(meuse.spdf)   

# create underlying grid
s.grid <- spsample(meuse.voro, type = "regular", n = 6000)

# calculate kriging
 # create variogram
lzn.vgm <- variogram(log(zinc)~1, meuse.spdf) # calculates sample variogram values 
lzn.fit <- fit.variogram(lzn.vgm, model=vgm(1, "Sph", 900, 1)) # fit model

plot(lzn.vgm, lzn.fit) # plot the sample values, along with the fit model

# calculate kriging
lzn.kriged <- krige(log(zinc) ~ 1, meuse.spdf, s.grid, model=lzn.fit)


# extract the unique x and y locations in the grid
ux<-unique(coordinates(lzn.kriged)[,1])
uy<-unique(coordinates(lzn.kriged)[,2])

# extract the predicted values and format var1.pred into a matrix of gridded values
predmat3 <- matrix(lzn.kriged$var1.pred, length(ux), length(uy))

# display the data

filled.contour(x = seq(0,1, length.out = nrow(predmat3)),
               y = seq(0,1, length.out = ncol(predmat3)),
               z = predmat3,
               col = brewer.pal(6,"Purples"), nlevels = 5)
```

Comment: First, I am completely baffled on the generation of voronoi polygons to create the kriging grid, it is quite unnecessary. Out of curiosity, have you searched the forum? Not only has this question been answered multiple times but addressed in very recent history. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192564/error-in-in-predict-gstat-in-r/192683#192683 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191351/creating-spatialpolygons-in-r/191403#191403

Comment: Coll ! thank, I didn't see those ones... I'll check it ! :)